# Measuring execution time of async code snippets

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am having trouble with my function for measuring execution time of async code snippets, so I created a console app for easier testing. I was trying to see if the time required for downloading a 200MB file corresponds to the output of the program. However, the app stops executing right after the first command of the code snippet finishes with the output "22 ms". Any ideas why this is happening?

In my real app with a GUI, which is inherently multi-threaded, the measured times were also unrealistic. I tried inserting "Task.Delay" calls into the snippets and it seemed to have no impact on the measured values.

For the sake of brevity, I shortened the code from the real app. Any ideas why this is not working? Alternative ideas on how to measure the time execution of async code snippets?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    private static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        await MeasureExecutionTimeAsync(
            async () => {
                // download a 200MB file
                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://web4host.net/200MB.zip");

                // this never gets executed
                var array = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                File.WriteAllBytes("C:/mytmp/bytefile.xxx", array);
            }
        );
    }

    private static async Task MeasureExecutionTimeAsync(Action measuredAction)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        await Task.Run(measuredAction);

        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a fairly common "`Task` within a `Task`" problem.  The way you have things at the moment, you're not measuring the time for the inner-task to execute, but the time for the outer task (which just creates the inner-task) to execute, and that is of course almost zero.

Comment: The primary problem is due to the use of `async void`. By passing an `async` lambda to an `Action` delegate parameter, this code is instructing the compiler to write an `async void` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the line

```
await Task.Run(measuredAction);
```

Try this instead

```
private static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        Func<Task> action = async () =>
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://web4host.net/200MB.zip").ConfigureAwait(false);

            // this never gets executed
            var array = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            File.WriteAllBytes("C:/mytmp/bytefile.xxx", array);
            return;
        };

        await MeasureExecutionTimeAsync(action);
    }

    private static async Task MeasureExecutionTimeAsync(Func<Task> measuredAction)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        await measuredAction.Invoke();

        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
    }
```

Comment: Or simply `await measuredAction();` instead of using `Invoke()`.

Comment: How to measure time taken for individual tasks in `Task.WhenAll`